# dagger2 Inject field NullPointerException

Tags: android, dagger-2

I used dagger2 in my project, but the injection field is always null. Here is the code.

> sorry, my english is poor.
>   Thanks in advance.

Module

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().build();
    }
}
```

Component

```
@Component(modules = RetrofitModule.class)
public interface RetrofitComponent {

    void inject(Activity activity);

}
```

And in MainActivity, I write this

```
DaggerRetrofitComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
```

But the Retrofit is always null. How can I solve it?

Comment: Where do you call `inject()`?

Comment: MainActivity - onCreate()

Comment: It also looks like you're forgetting to pass the instance of `RetrofitModule` when creating the component, you should be calling `.retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule())`.

Comment: DaggerRetrofitComponent.builder().retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule()).build().inject(this);

Comment: Android studio tells me retrofitModule method is deprecated

Comment: Then find out the reason for deprecation and switch to a newer approach, I'm not up-to-date with Dagger developments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not inject this way to your Activity class!

change your component like this and specify the exact name of your Activity:

```
@Component(modules = RetrofitModule.class)
public interface RetrofitComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

}
```

and then perhaps also you have to change your module like this or anything else that fit your need:

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {

    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://google.com").build();
    }
}
```

By the way, make sure you have written @Inject before Retrofit declaration in your activity:

```
@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;
```

> note that: if you want to have singleton provide in your module, the
>   whole component cannot remain unstopped and it must be annotated
>   @Singleton.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry, I was busy a few days ago. I try it just now, it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that, don't forget to confirm the answer using green check ✅